# How to get the model from the General>About tab iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model, settings, device

I am trying to get the model of my device. I don't mean "iPhone" or "iPod Touch" by using

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSLog(@"%@", [device model]);
```

I mean the model from Settings>General>About. It looks something like "MC469B". Does anyone know how to get that?

Thanks
Clinton

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. Why would you want that?

Use these to get what you need:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];
```

Comment: My boss wants it for some analytic stuff

Comment: use those and you get your analytic stuff. Those methods give evreything you need/can get.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get it via public API. But wait... why do you want to get it?

Comment: My boss wants it for some analytic stuff.

Comment: Tell your boss that there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

[[UIDevice currentDevice] as mentioned by Arvin Am & Josh Caswell are the way to go, however you should read the SDK to see what the available iOS version has.  Some calls will be deprecated while others will only be supported in newer versions.

ie. UUID vs. UDID